# xargs usage syntax

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, suse

I am trying to search for a particular string within zipped files but cannot get the 'xargs' syntax correct.

The files unzip/zip correctly but xargs is actually searching for nothing (we are looking for failed TLS EMails).

Can anyone give me some pointers about the correct xargs syntax?

```
for filename in $( ls -1 ${HOST}-mail-2018${1}[0-9][0-9]* )
do
  filetype=${filename##*.}
  case $filetype in
    bz2)
        unzipper="bzip2 -d "
        zipper="bzip2"
        unzfile=${filename%.${filetype}}
        ;;
    gz)
        unzipper="gzip -d "
        zipper="gzip "
        unzfile=${filename%.${filetype}}
        ;;
    xz)
        unzipper="xz -d "
        zipper="xz "
        unzfile=${filename%.${filetype}}
       ;;
    *)
        echo "Unknown compression type for file $filename"
        break
        ;;
   esac
        #  Testing:    echo $unzipper $zipper $unzfile
        echo $unzipper $zipper $filename $unzfile

   eval ${unzipper} ${filename}
   grep 'Cannot .*TLS' ${unzfile} | sed 's/^.*]: //' | sed 's/:.*//' |  xargs fgrep
   eval ${zipper} ${unzfile}
done
exit 0
```

Comment: It's not clear why you're using `xargs` at all. Isn't `grep PATTERN | sed ...` enough? Also, you shouldn't zip and unzip back the files; simply `gzip -cd file | grep PATTERN` or `bzip -cd file | grep ..` (or `zgrep`, `bzgrep`) will do. And you shouldn't determine file type from the extension: use `type=\`file -i filename\`` then `case $type in application/gzip;*) ...;; application/x-bzip2;*) ... esac`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for filename in "$HOST-mail-2018$1"[0-9][0-9]*; do
    case $filename in
        *.gz)  g=zgrep  ;;
        *.bz2) g=bzgrep ;;
        *.xz)  g=xzgrep ;;
        *) printf 'Unknown filetype for "%s"\n' "$filename" >&2
           exit 1   # or continue or break
    esac

    "$g" 'Cannot .*TLS' "$filename"
done
```

Each compression tool comes with a corresponding `grep` tool. These are, for `gzip`, `bzip2` and `xz`, called `zgrep`, `bzgrep` and `xzgrep` respectively.  By using these there is no need to explicitly uncompress and recompress the files.

The script above picks the correct `grep` depending on the file suffix.  One could arguably use plain `grep` for any unknown suffix.  See below for how to do this without looking at filename suffixes (using the `file` tool).

Note how we *don't* need to use `ls` to loop over the set of files, and that the variable expansions need to be double quoted.

I ignored the `sed` calls that you have in your code as I don't know what the purpose of these are.  I also removed the `exit 0` at the end of the code as it would mask any other exit status of the script if it exited the loop.

---

Using the MIME-type of a file to select the correct `grep` tool:

```
for filename in "$HOST-mail-2018$1"[0-9][0-9]*; do
    case $( file -b -i "$filename" ) in
        text/plain*)          g=grep   ;;
        application/x-gzip*)  g=zgrep  ;;
        application/x-bzip2*) g=bzgrep ;;
        application/x-xz*)    g=xzgrep ;;
        *) printf 'Unknown filetype for "%s"\n' "$filename" >&2
           exit 1   # or continue or break
    esac

    "$g" 'Cannot .*TLS' "$filename"
done
```

This would correctly pick the correct `grep` tool regardless of what the filename suffix was (as long as the file was of one of the supported filetypes).  I've also added plain `grep` for ordinary text files.

Related:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)
- [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what do to instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985)

Comment: Thank you - you have made my day - my shell scripting skills are *extremely* limited and I was trying to butcher another script to get what I needed.  What you have provided is much simpler!

Comment: please don't encourage determining the file type from the extension; that's what `file -i` is for.

Comment: @mosvy Added that now.

Comment: that should be `application/x-gzip*)`, etc -- at least on my machine, `file -bi` also appends a `; charset=binary` to the output.

Comment: @mosvy Not on mine, but ok.

Comment: it really does on vanilla installations of debian 9.5, centos7 and freebsd-11.2